# On click of pop up doesn't clear the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a popup that has some radio button and input fields. There's a `handleClick` function on the `OK` button that does some work with the updated state and closes the popup. I'm trying to clear the state properties once these operations are performed and the pop up closes.

```
handleClick = () => {
  if(this.state.val === "1") {
    //do something
  } else if (this.state.val === "2") {
    //do something
  }
  //once if conditions are performed, clear the state
  this.setState({val: "0"}); //this is what i do right now
}
```

Doing `setState` isn't updating the state when I reopen the pop up.

Comment: Can you provide all the relevant code?

Comment: there's a lot of code and data passing between components for me to post it all. so i've narrowed it down to what i believe is the crux of it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, try this add setstate, in the end, change the state of inputs/radio buttons to empty.

```
handleClick = () => {
  if(this.state.val === "1") {
    //do something
  } else if (this.state.val === "2") {
    //do something
  }
  //once if conditions are performed, clear the state
  this.setState({val: "" or null }); //keep it empty or null
}
```

and also the radio input add checked method and pass the state to it so that if it null/empty it will be unchecked

```
<input type="radio" checked={this.state.val} />
```

**Or 2nd method you can use reset() method.**

add a ref to your form element like this

```
<form ref={(input) => this.resetForm = input}></form>

handleClick = () => {
  if(this.state.val === "1") {
    //do something
  } else if (this.state.val === "2") {
    //do something
  }
  //Use the ref to target the form and apply reset method to it
  this.resetForm.reset();
}
```

Comment: that's pretty much what i've done including the bit:
`<input type="radio" checked={this.state.val} />`

Comment: Can you try with false like this  this.setState({val: false }) and upated the original post with another method